# Can't inject a named persistence unit in Quarkus repository

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, reactive

I'm trying to inject a named persistence unit in a `PanacheRepositoryBase` and the application fails to initialise with the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory and qualifiers [@PersistenceUnit(value = "primary")]
    - java member: com.demo.repository.PeopleRepository#entityManagerFactory
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase<com.demo.entity.People, java.util.UUID>, com.demo.repository.PeopleRepository, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.demo.repository.PeopleRepository]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:428)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:524)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:260)
    ... 13 more
```

**application.properties:**

```
quarkus.datasource."primary".db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource."primary".reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
quarkus.datasource."primary".username=postgres
quarkus.datasource."primary".password=root
quarkus.datasource."primary".jdbc=false

quarkus.hibernate-orm."primary".datasource=primary
quarkus.hibernate-orm."primary".database.default-schema=app1
quarkus.hibernate-orm."primary".database.generation.create-schemas=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm."primary".database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm."primary".packages=com.demo.entity
```

**Repository:**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PeopleRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<People, UUID> {

    @PersistenceUnit("primary") // import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnit;
    @Inject
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
}
```

Just changing as follow, works fine:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=root
quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema=app1
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation.create-schemas=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.packages=com.demo.entity
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PeopleRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<People, UUID> {

    @Inject
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
}
```

**pom.xml (Quarkus 2.7.5.Final):**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple persistance unit are not supported at the moment with Hibernate Reactive on Quarkus, see https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive#hr-limitations